# Measure, Integration and Linear Functionals.

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

Ever since I began learning Measure Theory and Integration my mind was shocked to know how many different ways of defining an integral (I am mostly interested in LC Hasudorff spaces) there were. At first I thought that this was a mere coincidence but is the following interpretation correct:

By virtue of Riesz representation theorem (the measure theoretic one) we know that all linear functionals (on nice spaces of fuctions) can be regarded as certain integral operators in the Lebesgue sense. Could the Daniell integral be motivated by saying that an integral and a Linear functional are *the same thing*.

Secondly I would like to know how one can formulate problems in measure theory in a sistematic way. For example I know that in differential geometry, to get new insights, it is sufficient to change your references and differentiate a few times to get relations. How could I get mass-produced measure theoretic formulae or theorems?

Comment: First you have to work very hard.  Secondly you have to be very talented.  I know of no other way!

Comment: Try to generalize theorems of differential geometry to work for non-smooth functions using measure theoretic approximation arguments. I believe this is called geometric measure theory.